# WCF message security in .net core

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-core, .net-4.8

I need to connect to a WCF external service.
The external service is written in the .NET framework. The binding to the service is wsHttpBinding with message security:
(from the binding configuration:

```
<security>
       <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="false"
        establishSecurityContext="false" />
</security>
```

I conducted research online and I discovered there is no support for WCF message security in .net Core yet.
https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3424

I wanted to know if anyone found a way to connect to wcf services with message security through .net core.

Thank you for your help

Comment: For posterity, the ultimate link for tracking purposes should be: https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/3424

Comment: Maybe you can look at this.https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/4045#issuecomment-577854822